# How do I convert an object to a nbt of type INBT in Minecraft Forge for Minecraft 1.15

Tags: java, object, minecraft-forge

I was working on my Minecraft mod recently and while working on the return statement of a function, I found out it needs an instance of INBT for the return type. I have a custom object that I need to convert to an NBT of type `INBT`? 
Here is the function:

```
public INBT writeNBT(Capability<IAllergies> capability, IAllergies instance, Direction side) {

        return null;

    }
```

I have looked at the type hierarchy of `INBT` and found nothing that might be of any use.

Thanks in advance,
Kid Koder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. 
What I did was created an `ObjectNBT` class the implemented `INBT`, and wrote a few methods to get/set the `Object` here is what my final class looked like:

```
public class ObjectNBT implements INBT {

    public Object object;

    public ObjectNBT(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public byte getId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public INBTType<?> func_225647_b_() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public INBT copy() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ITextComponent toFormattedComponent(String indentation, int indentDepth) {
        return new StringTextComponent(indentation + indentDepth);
    }
}
```

Feel free to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't be creating your own class.
It depends on what you want, but there are many classes, from CompountNBT (which is a bit like a Map), ListNBT (a list of INBT), to BooleanNBT, StringNBT, IntegerNBT etc.
Look at the type hierachy of INBT and pick the one you need.